# Prove that $\int_{X}\exp(f(x))d\mu(x)\cdot\int_{X}\exp(-f(x))d\mu(x)\geq\mu(X)^{2} $

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{S},\mu)$ a measure space, and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. I have to prove that

$$\int_{X}\exp(f(x))d\mu(x)\cdot\int_{X}\exp(-f(x))d\mu(x)\geq\mu(X)^{2}.$$

I think it has something to do with Chebyshev's inequality, but I do not know how to conclude that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ($ \int|fg|\leqslant \sqrt{\int f^2}\sqrt{\int g^2} $ ) with $g(x):=\exp(f(x) /2)$ and $h(x):=\exp(-f(x) /2)$ and take squares.